# Do crits affect bonus damage / heals?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

A normal hit does damage like so:

```
MainHandDamage + OffhandDamage + StandardHealthFactor + BonusDamage
```

(Each component can be broken down further, but that's not relevant here.)

However, I'm not entirely sure which components are affected by a Critical Hit.  The most likely cases seem to be

```
(MainHandDamage + OffhandDamage + StandardHealthFactor) *
(1 + CritPercentage*SurgePercentage) + BonusDamage
```

and

```
(MainHandDamage + OffhandDamage + StandardHealthFactor + BonusDamage) *
(1 + CritPercentage*SurgePercentage)
```

In other words, is bonus damage (or healing) added in before or after the critical multiplier is applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://dulfy.net/2014/04/24/swtor-mechanics-basics-understanding-expected-damage/#Critical_Chance_vs_Shield_Chance) bonus damage is applied first:

> Recall the three components that affect Tooltip Damage are Weapon Damage, Damage Bonus & Base Level Damage. We previously established the following:
>
> - Main Hand Weapon Damage ranging from 679 to 1,262
> - Damage Bonus of 2,222
> - Base Level Damage of 542
> - Off-Hand Weapon Damage ranging from 204 to 379
>
> The average total Main Hand damage is:
>
> **(679 + 1,262)/2 + 2,222 + 542 = 3,735**

and then:

> Next, let’s assume the following:
>
> - Main Hand Special Accuracy of 110%
> - Off-Hand Special Accuracy of 77%
> - Critical Chance of 30%
> - Critical Multiplier of 75%
> - Target’s Armor Mitigation of 35%
>
> Our expected damage from the Main Hand is equal to:
>
> **3,735 * [1 + (30% * 75%)] * (1 – 35%) = 2,974**

The calculation uses the bonus damage in the base value of 3,735.

I cannot think of how this could be verified, but the author makes this assumption.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like solid info.  I suppose it could be verified finding the maximum value if the bonus damage didn't have crit applied, and then repeating the same hit over and over to see if it ever exceeds that value.

Comment: I think at one point there were skills without a damage range, not sure whether there are still any like that.